# css - Align relative positioned div to bottom of other

Tags: css

I've the following:

**HTML (partial)**:

```
<div id="page">
        <div id="header">
           <div id="logo">
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" />
           </div>
           <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <!-- how many <li>s as need -->
                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

    #page {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        width: 97%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #header {
            position: relative;
            height: auto;
            min-width: 100%;
            margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
            display: inline-block;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

            #header #logo {
                float: left;
            }

                #header #menu ul {
                    list-style-type: none;
                }

                    #header #menu ul li {
                        height: 2em;
                        line-height: 2em;
                    }

        #content {
            position: relative;
            margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
            width: 95%;
        }

        #footer {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 260px;
        }
```

Explaining:

There is a container div (#page). Within it there are #header, #content and #footer.
 #header space is split horizontally between #logo and #menu.

The problem:

I need to position #menu at bottom of #header but yet at side of #logo. I'm not getting it without break layout. How can I do this?

When new menu items be added, they should make menu go up, not down, this is why I need to do what I said above. The fist image below illustrates how I want to do and second how it actually is (lighter parts are within the darker and yes, it is a mobile layout):

**First Image:**

[image: First Image]

**Second Image:**

[image: Second Image]

And please, no JavaScript, just pure CSS.
Thanks for attention, bye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing display property of the #header to table, display of the #logo and #menu to 'table-cell' and verticaly align them to the bottom - it should do what you need

```
 #header {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        min-width: 100%;
        margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
        display: table;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #logo {
            display:table-cell;
            vertical-align:bottom;
    }

    #menu {display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;}
```

selector in your css `#header #logo` is too much because identifiers cannot duplicate so `#logo` is really enough

here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6xBvR/1/

Comment: I need to use `display: inline-block;` in #header to it be centered by `text-align: center;` on #page.
And `display: table/table-cell;` didn't works as I expect. #menu is vertically centered and a big space is added between it and #logo, at least is what your example shows.
Because of all this details, desired alignment is being so hard to me.

Thanks for answering!

Comment: `#header` will be always centered firstly because it has left and right margin set to `auto`, secondly its width is set to 100% which means that you will never see if it is centered or aligned left or right. My example works exactly as you wanted - #menu is vertically aligned **to the bottom** and all the spaces you have seen were made by margins and padding of an `ul` element. I just added `margin:0;padding:0;` to css of UL and now it looks exactly as your image: http://jsfiddle.net/6xBvR/2/

Comment: Seems to work but I tried here and `margin:0; padding:0;` in `ul` is making no difference. See: http://i.imgur.com/gsBjp4c.jpg

And #logo seems to be a little above #menu on bottom border...
Note: all elements have margin and padding set to 0 here (applied to global selector).

Comment: It is because alignment of an `img`. To fix it just add to css one more rule: `#logo img { vertical-align:bottom; }`. If you want to control spacing between #logo and #menu set `width:1%` on `#logo` and now you can control it with `margin-right` of the `img` ... http://jsfiddle.net/6xBvR/5/

Comment: Many thanks! Your soluctions worked fine, except I couldn't make `#menu` to fill restaming space to `#logo`. I got perfect result using Flexbox, which I think is a more beautiful way to do. As Flexbox isn't yet fully supported by browsers, I'll use your way as a fallback if I get `#menu` filling the space (I tried several ways, but no one solved).

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0px;` to `#header #logo`:

```
#header #logo {
     float: left;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0px;
}
```

Should fix your problem. You could also truncate `#header #logo` to just `#logo`.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this and don't work. It breaks the layout.
And thanks for your tip, I truncated it and other similar here.

Comment: @Tiago Could you specify in what regard it breaks the layout? I'll try to work it out.

Comment: `position: absolute;` make it to leave the position I set.
But don't worry, @webdev-dan's answer seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use float, I'd use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:bottom`

```
#logo {  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

#menu {  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

But you will need to set some widths.

I alos needed to remove padding from the `ul`

```
#menu ul {margin-bottom:0px}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pLeUD/